# Newtonsoft Json token name and value

Tags: .net, json, vb.net

Tell me what I do wrong.

I have a Json format like this

```
    {"RuleOne": "1", "RuleTwo": "Two", "RuleFive": "[1-5]"}
```

I can have many different rules for each json string. Each rule evaluate with the same algorithm. So i know that RuleOne will always be a number, that RuleTwo will always be a string and that RuleFive will always be a range and so on. My evaluate method do all this. This is not my question.

I use a the Newtonsoft.Json library and Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

How can I evaluate the name and value of a token?

```
    For Each token In json.First.SelectTokens(String.Empty)
        Select Case token.??Name??()
            Case "RuleOne"
                DoThisJob(token.??Value??)
            Case "RuleTwo"
                DoThisOtherJob(token.??Value??)
        End Select
    Next
```

Comment: Because it's dynamic and I don't need to deserialize if I can quickly request what I need

Comment: Yes i deleted that comment. I didn't get your question then. But now I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through the properties of the `JObject` by getting them using the `Properties()` function like this:

```
For Each token In json.Properties()
    Select Case token.Name
        Case "RuleOne"
            DoThisJob(token.ToObject(Of Object))
        Case "RuleTwo"
            DoThisOtherJob(token.ToObject(Of Object))
    End Select
Next
```

**Note** - I have used `Properties()` directly on `json`. If your data structure in JSON varies, you can modify `json`. However, the task you mentioned in the question can be accomplished using the above method.

Comment: Actually yes my data structure in JSON varies

Comment: So the above method didn't work even after customizing?

Comment: I think I don't really understand what exactly is a JToken ad how Json Newtonsoft works